# Phonegap Ajax request to port 8000

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova

I'm making a Phonegap app and need to retrieve some information from an external service through an ajax request.

How can I make an ajax request from a Phonegap app to localhost at port 8000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the request to localhost the request will be routed to the device itself. If you want your phone/device to talk to your desktop machine you will need to specify it's hostname or IP address.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that I was trying to connect to localhost when in reality the server isn't running on the mobile device

Answer (score 1):

Send the Ajax request to `http://localhost:8000/path/to/script`